# Angular [webpack-dev-server] Connection Looping under Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webpack-dev-server

For my Angular project(Angular 14, webpack-dev-server 4.9.3), web-pack-server disconnected and trying to reconnect message constantly looping if the application is run under Chrome. But the message does not show if run under Edge.

The message is shown under Console log.

[image: Console log: Disconnected!, Trying to reconnect..., Live Reloading enabled.]

Comment: Are you using `webpack-cli`? Could you please share your Webpack config file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I suddenly have the same issue

Comment: on an angular project, I had this problem in all browsers, regardless of extensions. Everything was solved when I turned off the antivirus.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I added an exception to the `localhost` address in my Kaspersky antivirus.

Under Security/Security Settings/Safe Browsing/Advanced Settings/Trusted URLs,
click `+Add` and type in `*localhost*`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of solutions:

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution**

Run `npx webpack serve --allowed-hosts all`

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution**

Go to your config, in the `devServer` object, replace `allowedHosts: 'auto'` with `allowedHosts: ['all']`

Comment: I am running on Windows 10. Where is the config file containing allowedHosts?

Answer (score 0):

I would try opening your site in a Chrome Incognito tab.

If it works there, you know you have some plugin that does some weird sh...